# Find location of a line of code after changes using Git

Tags: git

Is it possible to find the updated location of a line of code between commits using git?

For example, let's says you want to track `README.md#L10`. You proceed to:
1. Add five lines to the beginning of `README.md`, and commit
2. Remove three lines from the beginning of `README.md`, and commit
3. Rename `README.md` to `CONTRIBUTING.md`

What was previously `README.md#L10` is now `CONTRIBUTING.md#L12`.

Given an initial commit, a file and line of code, and a second commit, how can I programatically find the updated file and line of code in the second commit?

Comment: Using Git blame? (Maybe in combination with a gui, eg tortoiseGit)

Comment: Using `git diff` ?

Comment: @Julian that'd be good for a one-off solution, but I'm hoping for a programatic solution - question udpated

Comment: @phili_b That's what I'm leaning towards, but I haven't seemed to find any options that output what I'm looking for

Comment: http://xahlee.info/linux/git_diff.html

Comment: @phili_b `git diff 3d5cf 5aa95 myfilename` is the closest to what I need, but I'm looking for a way to specify line number as well, and get a filename + line number in turn

Comment: You might want to use [`git log -S`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt) in phase 2, when searching for the commits changing some content.

Comment: It's `git log -L`, hunt it up.

Comment: @jthill Hum :-) It was not a mislink on my part. Genuinely ignored the option. Great. Even easier like that, indeed, forget `-S` here.